# preg_match & regex to find something

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to use preg_match & regex to find all video qualitys.So I want to search 128, 500, 750, 1000, 1500 pixel qualitys. I need return all qualitys in array. How can I do it?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=350000
128/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=750000
500/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1000000
750/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1250000
1000/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1750000
1500/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
```

Comment: Any attempts yet? And it doesn't look like you need a regex to do something like that.

Comment: `preg_match_all('/(.*?)\/prog_index.m3u8/mis', $url, $C);
print_r($C);`

Comment: I found:
`preg_match_all('/(.*?)\/prog_index.m3u8/', $url, $C);
print_r($C[1]);`

Comment: @user3449464: And what is the result of your attempt? It's seem fine for me.

Comment: Well, now you got it :) Escape the period though. Better be safe than sorry!

Comment: @M42 The flags made things a bit... [excessive](http://regex101.com/r/mV0fO2).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `explode` instead.

```
$pixel_arr = array();
foreach(explode(PHP_EOL,$str) as $v)
{
    if(strpos($v,'/')!==false)
    {
        $v=explode('/',$v);
        $pixel_arr[]=array_shift($v);
    }
}
print_r($pixel_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 128
    [1] => 500
    [2] => 750
    [3] => 1000
    [4] => 1500
)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/124790)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regexp, if you want to:

```
preg_match_all( '/([0-9]+)\//', $str, $matches );
print_r( $matches[1] );
```

But, really, explode will be much faster.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
preg_match_all('/^\d+/m', $str, $m);
```